# Convert to fluid/responsive design from 960 gs 12 column

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am a beginner when it comes to web development. The thing is that I have built my portfolio site. I set the width of the body at 1600px because that is the width of my banner background as it appears in my photoshop prototype. I am also using 960gs 12 columns. When I preview the site in browsers, I find it too wide.

What I wanted to do now is to make it a responsive one.

Here is the structure of my code:

```
<div id="banner">
  <div class="container_12">
      <!----banner content here----->
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {width: 1600px;}
#banner {background-img:"bgimagehere"; height: 660px;}
```

Hope somebody could help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

set

```
img{width:100%, height:100%}
```

will make images responsive or use media queries to set image dimensions for smaller and larger screen devices.

Doing either of the above will make your site responsive. or use bootstrap, initializr or other famous frameworks that help you build better.

Hope this helps

Comment: So images can also be responsive? Will try this one out.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have 2 problems:

1) 1600px is too big for you.
2) You need a Carousel (your title says this, but your explanation is kind of vague)

So, instead of using a fixed width in `px`, use a relative one, like `100%`. For your second problem, I recommend using [Flex Slider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/). Please try and be more clear about what your problem is.

**EDIT:**

Okay, your question title is better now. Carousel does not apply.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion there. Corrected it as soon as I saw it. Will just make another thread for the carousel.
.

Thank you for your answer. Will try that. But just a follow up, will  changing width to a relative one affect the background image?

Comment: @gelopez Please explain. What do you mean? Can you create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I will come back tomorrow to answer follow up (EST). Good night!